# Is transferring money from a company where you're a director to a company where you're an employee considered money laundering?

Tags: finance

Say you are a full-time employee of company A, and company A providing services to company B, where you are a director and a shareholder. Company B transfers money to company A. I've been told it can be viewed as potential money laundering, is it true?

Comment: Where is this? Which Jurisdiction applies? Maybe Serbia-Montenegro, Republic of Korea, Venezuela, or New Jersey?

Comment: That would seem to depend on the facts.  Any transfer of money could be "potentially" money laundering.  It's certainly not _inherently_ money laundering.

Answer (score 3):

> Is transferring money from a company where you're a director to a company where you're an employee considered money laundering?

No. The scenario you outline seems too broad and generic. There are many possible, lawful reasons why company B could transfer money to its supplier, company A. Some examples are payment for the services that company A provided, an indemnization/settlement, and a buyout.

The mere fact that B's director/shareholder is A's employee does not render the transaction(s) money laundering.

Also, the statutory elements of money laundering vary by jurisdiction.

Comment: I actually wonder how money laundering would work in this scenario. Starting with a criminal having $100,000 from drug sales for example.